# AWS RDS publish custom conditional event

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Here is the problem we are trying to solve. We need AWS RDS to send events based on a database field value and the payload of the event should contain values from another column.
So let's say I have the table with 2 columns: `Date` and `Content`. I want RDS to send an event with `Content` when `Date` equals to the current date and time.

Does AWS RDS have these capabilities? If no, what tools could solve that?

Comment: Send an event where? What db?

Comment: Doesn’t matter, SNS, HTTP call etc

Comment: Those are each different procols, so it likely does matter. Some more focus or detail would help us answer your question.

Comment: @RodrigoM there supported by AWS channels and they suite me perfectly. The question is more about if it’s possible to generate such a conditional event and post it through any of the supported protocols

Comment: Got it. Well Lamaba SNS  would work.

Answer (score 0):

RDS itself has no such capabilities that I'm aware of. I would consider a scheduled Lambda to run a  database query, and send your desired  notification via SNS when your data condition is met.